# How to dock, setup Query Manager

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

Anyone know how can I dock the Manage Query panel to right? My firebird version is 2.5, IBExpert version is 2015.12.11

After I click on the button the Queries window (on my first picture) will be popup. I also checked options in the IBEXPERT.tb file under Appdata\Roaming\HK-Software\IBEXPERT directory. Everything seems ok...

My Window looks like...

[image]

I want form like...

[image]

I checked all settings but could not find. Thanks for the answers, I hope you know, it is so inconvenient to use now.

Comment: Your screenshots are not of Firebird (which doesn't have a GUI), what tool is this? Also _"2015.12.11"_ is not a Firebird version number

Comment: Sorry for that, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double click the Query Manager window caption or drag it over the right edge of the SQL Editor window.

Please read here about the User Database:
http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.IBExpertUserDatabase

You have to use the IBExpert User Database (Options | Environment Options | User Database) to get a dockable Query Manager window. Otherwise it is just an ordinary, not dockable window.

Answer (score 0):

check out the toolbar button "Manage queries". This button allows to toggle the query-set section.

[image: IBExpert SQL Editor]

Comment: I checked, thanks. After I click on the button the Queries window (on my first picture) will be popup. I also checked options in the IBEXPERT.tb file under Appdata\Roaming\HK-Software\IBEXPERT directory. Everything seems ok...